# for loop with range

Tags: c++, for-loop

I need to make a program that calculates for an entered N all prime numbers in a range from N-10 to N+10. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.Why Y is not increasing?

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cmath>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    int N, Y;
    bool Prime=true;
    cout<<"Enter N: ";
    cin>>N;
    Y=N;
    for (int i=1; i<=N+10;i++){
         for(int k = 2; k <= sqrt(Y); k++,Y++){
             if(Y%k== 0) {
             Prime = false;
             }
         }
         if(Prime && Y>1)
         cout<< "Number " <<Y
         << " is Prime."<<endl;
         }
 }
```

Comment: Can you comment your code. Because your variables mean nothing to me

Comment: You are incrementing `Y`  in the inner loop.

Comment: There are so many things wrong with this code it is hard to know where to begin.

Comment: I'm a beginner. not a pro. Yes, I know I'm incrementing Y in the inner loop, but it doesn't work when you run a program... :/

Comment: The outer loop should be `for(Y = N-10; Y <= N+10; Y++)` and not change `Y` inside.

Answer (score 0):

There are just too many things that are wrong.
Here's how it should be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main(){            
        int N;
        bool Prime;
        cin >> N;

        for (int i=1; i<=N+10;i++){
            Prime = true;
            int max = sqrt(i);
            for (int k = 2; k <= max; k++) {
                if((i % k) == 0) {
                    Prime = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (Prime && (i > 1))
                cout << "Number " << i << " is Prime." << endl;
        }
    return 0; 
}
```